# Counting cliques in a graph asymptotically

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Since $\binom{2n}{n} = \Omega(2^n)$, can we conclude that as $n$ grows, there are asymptotically $\Omega(2^n)$ possible locations of [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) of size $n$ in a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) with $2n$ vertices?

Comment: To be precise, $\binom{2n}{n}=\Omega(n^{-1/2}2^n)$, but not $\Omega(2^n)$. Otherwise, you are correct.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Great! You are welcome to convert this into an answer.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Could you provide a reference to a proof of this? When I check out a few terms of $\binom{2n}{n}$, it’s way larger than $2^n$. So presumably it has something to do with the nature of cliques in graphs?

Comment: Yeah, I was confused, it is actually $\binom{2n}n=\Omega(n^{-1/2}4^n)$. The proof is via Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stirling's approximation,
$$
\binom{2n}n
=\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}
\sim \frac{(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}\sqrt{2\pi( 2n)}}{\big(n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\big)^2}
=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$
Here, $f(n)\sim g(n)$ means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)=1$. This further implies that $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$, which of course implies $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$. We conclude that
$$
\binom{2n}{n}=\Omega(4^n\cdot n^{-1/2}).
$$